# Point Virtural Directory in IIS7 at a different URL/Domain

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, redirect, url-rewriting

When I used to use IIS 6 (or so) I'd often make a virtual directory on my local dev machine that pointed to the production assets/content directory(s). That way I could see all the most up to date content off production, without having to FTP it down from the production server.

Now I'm trying to do it in IIS 7 and can't see it.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Or has it been removed and I should use the IIS rewriter module?

Thanks in advance everyone!

-Evan

Comment: I'm surprised no one has read this... I was expecting a pretty quick response. :)

I'm thinking I may have put this in the wrong place. If anyone sees this, and can suggest a reason why people are not viewing it so much, please do let me know!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah man. This is so annoying, I don't think it's actually possible.

My conclusion is that this functionality was lost in IIS7. In my .net apps I use the rewriter in the web.config to achieve this result.